# How can I securely manage my client's PayPal merchant account as a web developer freelancer?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

Currently, when i need to access my customer's PayPal merchant account (to manage IPNs or to update notifications preferences for examples), i login to the account using his credentials and his 2FA (asking him the SMS code).

Is there a feature similar to Stripe Team which allows team members to access a PayPal merchant dashboard with their own credentials? Right here i am talking about the account dashboard, not the developer dashboard, but my question applies to both!

All of this doesn't seem very efficient and secure, is there another way?

Am i supposed to use my credentials only to develop the website (on developer.paypal.com) and never connect to the actual merchant's PayPal account? And ask the customer to do every manipulation on his account himself telling him the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you should only need to obtain API credentials to integrate with, which for current solutions are in the developer dashboard. Other account settings and operations in the account are not something web developers need access to, other than maybe some initial setup tweaks to the [website preferences](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/website) page. To the extent other settings matter, it is likely you are making wrong integration choices or using old legacy PayPal products (not good--for instance, you tagged the above with IPN -- what year is it? why would you be using IPN in 2023?)

Anyway, it is possible to [create and manage user access](https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/users/) within a PayPal account. This is usually only used for in-house staff, not a vendor/contractor since you should not need it, but in theory it can be used for what you're asking.

Comment: So you're suggesting that i should only interact with the API via the credentials provided by the client?

Comment: My client has IPNs enabled pointing to a 404 page (for whatever reason the former developer set this up) and i wanted to disable them, and my client doesn't seem to be able to do it himself! I think they aren't manageable from the API.

Comment: Thank you for the link, i couldn't find it myself! With a user created this way, will the user be able to access the developer dashboard? Is it related to the "Access APIs and developer support site" permission?

Comment: That is the permission. And yes, and old/invalid IPN URL should be removed from the configuration.